# LINQ Join DbFunction.AddDays vs. DateTime.AddDays

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the below LINQ query which has a simple logic to self join the collection with itself on two date columns. The date of one table is matched with the previous business date of the same table. Below is the LINQ join query:

```
var count = dbContext.NAVSummaries.Join(dbContext.NAVSummaries,
                        current => new { current.Portfolio, PD = current.ValueDate },
                        //previous => new { previous.Portfolio, PD = SqlFunctions.DatePart("dw", previous.ValueDate) == 1 ? previous.ValueDate.AddDays(-3) : SqlFunctions.DatePart("dw", previous.ValueDate) == 0 ? previous.ValueDate.AddDays(-2) : previous.ValueDate.AddDays(-1) },
                        previous => new { previous.Portfolio, PD = SqlFunctions.DatePart("dw", previous.ValueDate) == 1 ? DbFunctions.AddDays(previous.ValueDate, -3) : SqlFunctions.DatePart("dw", previous.ValueDate) == 0 ? DbFunctions.AddDays(previous.ValueDate, -2) : DbFunctions.AddDays(previous.ValueDate, -1) },
                        (outer, inner) => new { outer, inner })
```

For the above syntax visual studio gives me the following error:

> The type arguments for method
>   'System.Linq.Queryable.Join(System.Linq.IQueryable,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

When I interchange the commented syntax for the 'previous' innerKeySelector, the code builds but throws below runtime exception:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime
>   AddDays(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a
>   store expression.

...which is understandable. This made me replace the DateTime.AddDays to DbFunctions.AddDays. However, I have no clue why compile time error is thrown for the Join extension and what is the fix for it.

Comment: `DbFunctions.AddDays` returns a `Nullable<DateTime>`, while I'm assuming `ValueDate` is a non-nullable `DateTime`.  Therefore the data types in your join clauses don't match.

Comment: That worked @DStanley. Thanks

Comment: Then please mark as answered.